# Аккордеон в jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы появляющийся текст вылазил наверх?

```js
$(".closed .block").hide();
$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show").next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0 -10px -1px -10px;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.block {
  padding: 0;
}
.block_in {
  padding: 12px;
}
.box div.hide {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box div.hide:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.box div.hide span.h {
  display: block;
}
.box div.hide span.s {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.h {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.hide span.h {
  display: none;
}
.closed div.hide span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.h {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.s {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box closed">
  <h2>Toggle
    <span class="l"></span>
    <span class="r"></span>
  </h2>
  <div class="hide">
    <span class="s">Show</span>
    <span class="h">Hide</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block_in">
      буквыбуквыбуквы
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как сделать, чтобы появляющийся текст вылазил наверх?

Для этого Вам нужно поставить блок `.block` над `h2` и изменить код jquery:

```js
$(".closed .block").hide();
$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show").closest(".box").find(".block").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0 -10px -1px -10px;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.block {
  padding: 0;
}
.block_in {
  padding: 12px;
}
.box div.hide {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box div.hide:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.box div.hide span.h {
  display: block;
}
.box div.hide span.s {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.h {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.hide span.h {
  display: none;
}
.closed div.hide span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.h {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.s {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box closed">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block_in">
      буквыбуквыбуквы
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Toggle
    <span class="l"></span>
    <span class="r"></span>
  </h2>
  <div class="hide">
    <span class="s">Show</span>
    <span class="h">Hide</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

**UPD:**

Данный вариант позволяет тексту появляться вверху `h2`, но при этом `h2`смещается вниз. Если Вам нужно, чтобы `h2` был неподвижен, а появляющийся текст не сдвигал его, а двигался вверх, то Вам нужно переделать стили блоков `box`, `block`, `h2`, например так:

```js
$(".closed .block").hide();
$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show").closest(".box").find(".block").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #444;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0 0px -1px 0px;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.block {
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -45px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.block_in {
  padding: 12px;
}
.box div.hide {
  display: block !important;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DCDCDC inset;
}
.box div.hide:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.box div.hide span.h {
  display: block;
}
.box div.hide span.s {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.h {
  display: none;
}
.box div.show span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.hide span.h {
  display: none;
}
.closed div.hide span.s {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.h {
  display: block;
}
.closed div.show span.s {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box closed">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block_in">
      буквыбуквыбуквы
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>Toggle
    <span class="l"></span>
    <span class="r"></span>
  </h2>
  <div class="hide">
    <span class="s">Show</span>
    <span class="h">Hide</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Второй вариант подошёл, спасибо!